# React: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Tags: reactjs, dom

I'm trying to create the ability to format input text, however, the app is crashing and I'm receiving two errors. I'm receiving this error: `Cannot read property 'innerText' of null` whenever I try to type in either of the form fields and I get this error `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` when I click on the format buttons. I'm using React.js.

GitHub: https://github.com/Rahni1/mern_blog

How can I solve these errors?

Thanks!

```
class CreatePost extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      body: "",
      createdPost: "",
      error: "",
      underlined: false,
    };
    this.onUnderlineClick = this.onUnderlineClick.bind(this);
  }
  onUnderlineClick(event) {
    event.target.setAttribute(
      "class",
      !this.state.underlined ? "Selected" : ""
    );
    if (!this.state.underlined) {
      this.outputRef.current.innerHTML += "<u></u>";
    }
    this.setState({
      underlined: !this.state.underlined,
    });
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
  }
 
  formatText(text) {
    switch (true) {
     ...
      case this.state.underlined:
        const allUnderlined = this.outputRef.current.getElementsByTagName("u");
        const lastUnderlined = allUnderlined[allUnderlined.length - 1];
        lastUnderlined.innerText += text;
        break;
      default:
        this.outputRef.current.innerHTML += text;
        break;
    }
  }
  transferText() {
    const input = this.inputRef.current.value;
    const output = this.outputRef.current.innerHTML;
    let inputCounter = input.length - 1,
      outputCounter = output.length - 1,
      isTag = false;
    while (outputCounter > -1) {
      if (output[outputCounter] === ">") {
        isTag = true;
        outputCounter -= 1;
        continue;
      }
      if (isTag) {
        isTag = output[outputCounter] !== "<";
        outputCounter -= 1;
        continue;
      }
      if (inputCounter <= -1) {
        this.outputRef.current.innerHTML = this.outputRef.current.innerHTML.slice(
          outputCounter + 1
        );
        break;
      }
      else {
        let temp = this.outputRef.current.innerHTML;
        temp =
          temp.slice(0, outputCounter) +
          input[inputCounter] +
          temp.slice(outputCounter + 1);
        this.outputRef.current.innerHTML = temp;
        inputCounter -= 1;
        outputCounter -= 1;
      }
    }
  }
  changeHandler = (e) => {
    const input = this.inputRef.current.value;
    const output = this.outputRef.current.innerText;
    if (input.length > output.length) {
      const newText = input.slice(output.length);
      this.formatText(newText);
    } else {
      this.transferText();
    }
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  ... 
  render() {
    const { title, body } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div>     
          <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="title"
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                value={title}
              />
            </div>
            <span>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={this.onUnderlineClick}>
                <u>U</u>
              </button>
            </span>
            <div>
              <textarea
                ref={this.inputRef}
                className="Text"
                onChange={this.changeHandler}
                value={body}
              />
            </div>
            ...
          </form>
          </div>
          <div ref={this.outputRef}></div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
innerRef={r=>this.inputRef=r}
```

instead of

```
ref={this.inputRef}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still receiving `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` when I click on the format buttons, however, I'm now receiving `Cannot read property 'value' of null` when I try typing in the input fields which is a different error to before. @ShreeCharan

Comment: Try binding the transfer text and changehandler function as well
this.transferText= this.transferText.bind(this);
in the constructor

Comment: Also try printing this like console.log(this) in changeHandler function and check if it has the ref members

Comment: Also using refs when you change the state a lot is a bad idea. Check the docs here the clearly advise against that https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried binding them, however, I still received the same errors and when I tried printing `this` nothing printed. @ShreeCharan

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to update ref property:

```
ref={node => this.node = node}
```

after that update **changeHandler**

```
changeHandler = (e) => {
  const input = this.inputRef.value;
  ...
```

and make similar changes in all places where you use ref

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried making these changes however I'm still receiving the errors.  @AlekseyPolonka

Comment: what kind of error are you receiving? Also, using innerHTML is an antipattern, you should update elements in the render method.

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I was following an article to add a text formatting feature as I wasn't sure how to go about it but perhaps I'll take a look at a different approach. I'm receiving `Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null` when I click on the formatting buttons and `Cannot read property 'value' of null` when I try to type in the input fields. @AlekseyPolonka

Comment: @Rahni did you try to remove “current” from inputRef and outputRef?

Comment: Yes, when I removed `current` from both `inputRef` and `outputRef`, I received `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when I tried typing in the input fields so `input` and `output` were both `undefined`. @AlekseyPolonka

Comment: @Rahni then you didn't update the code correctly, here is the example https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-dew-g1ct9?file=/src/CreatePost.js